# Converting a buffer to char array for strtok

Tags: c, arrays, system-calls

I am having some trouble using system calls in C. I am trying to use `read` to read some input from `stdin`, then use strtok to load the values in an array, but I can't seem to do that right (I keep on getting segfault).

Here is the code I began with:

```
void read_input()
{
    char* c;
    read(0, c, 128);
    printf("%s", c);
}
```

So, this works fine, and I can print the output. However, I have tried several things next and they haven't worked. I have tried:

1. Creating an array `char arr[128]`, then using different variations of `strcpy`, `strncpy`, and `memcpy` to copy `c` into `arr`, but they haven't worked, and I get a segfault.

Actually, that's all I have tried. I am not sure how I am supposed to copy `c` into `arr` so I can use `strtok`. Can anyone explain?

Thanks

Edit:

Okay, this is my new code:

```
void
read_input()
{
    char arr[129];
    int r = read(0, arr, 129);
    printf("%s", arr);

    arr[r] = '\0';

    char* pch;

    pch = strtok(arr, " \n");

    while(pch != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", pch);
        pch = strtok(NULL, " \n");
    }
}
```

I am trying to read from stdin an input like "hi my name is john". This is the output I get from the printfs:

```
hi my name is john
�����hi
my
name
is
john
```

Why does the first token look like that? I noticed that if I dont add `arr[r] = '\0'`, then "john" will look similar to "hi". Is there something I need to do for the first character, similar to the last?

Comment: This can't work. Your `c` is uninitialized.

Comment: "this works fine" - are you sure? `read` has to write data to the memory your pointer points to, but it in fact doesn't point to anything. You should allocate some memory first

Comment: @EugeneSh. @ForceBru I am not "sure", per se, that it works fine. All I know is that `printf` prints the contents of `c`.

Comment: And even if you fix that, whatever read fills the char array with is unlikely to be 0 terminated.

Comment: Okay, I am a bit new to C, can someone show me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @JohnLexus, _where_ is `read` supposed to write the data? Is there (enough) memory to put this data into?

Comment: @ForceBru I suppose it's supposed to read it into `c`? So I need to malloc some memory, I guess? `char* c = malloc(128)` or something?

Comment: `malloc(129)` - you need an extra byte to store the NUL terminator character too, which you'll need to add as well

Comment: @JohnLexus, yes, you need to allocate memory

Comment: `read(2)` will not put a string terminator at the end, you have to do it with the result code of `read()`.

Answer (score 1):

You could directly go for this:

```
void read_input()
{
    char arr[128];
    read(0, arr, 128);
    printf("%s", arr);
}
```

Or the dynamic memory allocation route:

```
char *arr = malloc((sizeof(*arr) * 128) + 1);
if (arr == NULL)
{
    // handle error
}
int r = read(0, arr, 128);
arr[r] = '\0';
printf("%s", arr);
```

Comment: Why do you have the off-by-one difference between two codes?

Comment: @EugeneSh.Sorry, that was a typo, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @JohnLexus The question is actually for Leo :) The two codes above are not equivalent.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Oh, in my edit i made a similar mistake. Well I benefitted from it too anyways haha!

Answer (score 1):

Your second program doesn't work because you put the `NUL` terminator *after* the the call to `printf`. You need to do it *before* `printf`:

```
char arr[129];              // 128 + 1 for the NUL terminator
int r = read(0, arr, 128);
arr[r] = '\0';
printf("%s\n", arr);        // \n for better readbility of the output
```

You also need one more byte for the `NUL` terminator, hence the `129`.

`printf` with the `%s` format specifier prints `NUL` terminated strings. As you don't put the `NUL` before `printf`, latter displays all characters until it encounters a `NUL` hence the output you get:

```
hi my name is john
�����
...
```

This output may vary, it depends on the previous content of the `arr` buffer.

The first version is wrong because the `c` pointer is not initialized, it points nowhere. The program *may* appear to work correctly in this case, but this is so called "undefined behaviour", google that and keep in mind that "undefined behaviour" includes "apparently working fine".

Comment: Okay. I have one final question!

I am using 129 (or 128) right now. But I don't actually know the `nbytes` that I am reading in (which is the third argument in read). What is the conventional way of dealing with that?

Comment: If it reads 129 bytes you end up writing the 0 past the end of the array.

Comment: @ChrisTurner of course, thanks for pointing this out, edited-

Comment: @JohnLexus that's a _different_ question. The answer is not trivial.